# Data Annotation Condicional MVC4

Tags: c#, validação, asp.net-mvc-4

Pesquisei pacas aqui e nao encontrei uma soluçao pro que eu queria. Queria saber se alguem ja fez alguma coisa semelhante em MVC4.

**Model:**

```cs
public class Trabalhador
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public String Aposentado { get; set; }

    [Requerido caso o Aposentado seja "S"]
    public DateTime DataAposentadoria { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nome)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome)

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Aposentado)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Aposentado)

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataAposentadoria)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataAposentadoria)
```

Aqui esta o X da Questao, eu no meu formulario desejo todos os campos, entretanto quero que me force a digitar a Data da Aposentaria apenas no caso de um valor especifico no atributo Aposentado (que no caso seria "S" ou qualquer outro valor q eu queira).
Busquei em varios posts mesmo aqui no Stack, porem nenhum dos modelos funcionou.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713281/attribute-dependent-on-another-field/5079585#5079585
- http://miroprocessordev.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/aspnet-mvc-conditional-validation-using.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417113/asp-net-mvc-conditional-validation
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/simonince/conditional-validation-in-mvc

Comment: Talvez o atributo `RequiredIf` presente nesta resposta do SOEN te ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15975880/195417

Comment: Já posto a solução para você.

Answer (score 1):

Minha solução:

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DataAposentadoria : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var property = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty("Aposentado");

        if (property == null)
            return new ValidationResult("Propriedade desconhecida: 'Aposentado'");

        var propertyValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        if (propertyValue != null && propertyValue.ToString() == "S" && value == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Data de aposentadoria deve ser preenchida!");
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Para usar:

```
public String Aposentado { get; set; }

[DataAposentadoria]
public DateTime? DataAposentadoria { get; set; }
```

Explicando, quando ele entrar na propriedade, tentará achar se existe a propriedade "Aposentado", se existir ele pega o valor e valida.

Claro que você pode incrementar para colocar uma propriedade dinâmica.

Comment: Testei aqui essa solução e tambem não força a validaçao, caso a condição seja atendida.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode implementar um atributo que faça uma validação personalizada, da mesma forma que o `Required`, mas somente quando a condição for satisfeita, e usar este atributo ao invés do `Required`.

Neste atributo implemente a interface `IClientValidatable` para poder fazer a validação no client, quando estiver usando validação não obstrusiva, e implemente uma implementação de validação com javascript.

Um exemplo, está nesta resposta do SOEN:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15975880/195417

Adaptei o atributo da resposta apresentada acima para ter validação não obstrusiva no client:

```
public class RequiredIfAttribute : RequiredAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private String PropertyName { get; set; }
    private Object Comparand { get; set; }

    public RequiredIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object comparand)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        Comparand = comparand;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        var instance = context.ObjectInstance;
        var type = instance.GetType();
        var proprtyvalue = type.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(instance, null);

        if (proprtyvalue.ToString() == Comparand.ToString())
        {
            var result = base.IsValid(value, context);
            return result;
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> IClientValidatable.GetClientValidationRules(
        ModelMetadata metadata,
        ControllerContext context)
    {
        var requiredIfRule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        requiredIfRule.ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessageString;
        requiredIfRule.ValidationType = "requiredif";
        requiredIfRule.ValidationParameters.Add("propertyname", this.PropertyName);
        requiredIfRule.ValidationParameters.Add("comparand", this.Comparand);
        yield return requiredIfRule;
    }
}
```

Crie um arquivo de javascript, e o inclua na página com o campo a ser validado:

```
$.validator.addMethod("requiredif", function (value, element, params) {
    return $(params.propertyname).val() == params.comparand
        ? value != null && value != "" && value != undefined
        : true;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
    "requiredif",
    ["propertyname", "comparand"],
    function (options) {
        options.rules["propertyname"] = "#" + options.params.propertyname;
        options.rules["comparand"] = options.params.comparand;
        options.messages["requiredif"] = options.message;
    });
```

E use-o assim:

```
public class Trabalhador
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public String Aposentado { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("Aposentado", "S")]
    public DateTime DataAposentadoria { get; set; }
}
```

**Referência:**

- http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/tag/custom-unobtrusive-validation/
- http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-helpers,-forms-and-validation#Exercise7

Não consegui determinar a autoria do atributo `RequiredIf`... procurando no Google por `RequiredIfAttribute RequiredAttribute` retorna inúmeras fontes onde esse código é utilizado. Vou pesquisar mais, e se achar, faço referência aqui. Se alguém encontrar o autor, por favor, fique a vontade para editar a resposta, ou então fazer um comentário.

Comment: Obrigado brother, mas eu ja havia tentado essa solução, exatamente como voce postou, entretanto o formulario nao me força a validar os campos requeredif mesmo atendendo a condição.

Comment: Você está falando de fazer validação no client, antes de submeter o formulário? ... do jeito que eu postei aqui, é uma validação no servidor, e não no client.

Comment: Sim, seria exatamente a validação no cliente assim como é feito nos outros atributos,  a questão é porque o [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")] public String Nome { get; set; } é validado e o [RequiredIf("Aposentado", "S")] public DateTime DataAposentadoria { get; set; } não é validado =/

Comment: Editei a resposta com uma implementação que permite validação no client.

Comment: Miguel,  obrigado pela ajuda, porém ainda não funcionou, o meu DropDown tem a opçao de S ou N, quando eu coloco em S ele força a validação, botei um "T" apenas pra testar e mesmo alterando o valor do drop para T a validação ainda é forçada, sendo que essa validação deveria ser forçada apenas no Caso "S", esquisito, eu devo alterar alguma coisa no JS que você passou? pois o mesmo também ja está na tela e ainda assim nada, eu devo incluir ainda algumas bibliotecas de JS?

Comment: Erro meu... a validação estava sendo feita de forma errada. Corrigido.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o seu problema?

Comment: Ainda ñ miguel, continua na mesma, a validação é forçada mesmo eu jogando um valor diferente de "S" ("T" no caso apenas pra teste), vou tentar a solução proposta abaixo pelo FCCDias.

Comment: Eu não tenho como rodar isso aqui agora, para debugar e ver o que está errado. A solução do @FCCDias está muito parecida, com algumas pequenas diferenças... talvez funcione.

Comment: Obrigado senhores, mas infelizmente não funcionou, vou resolver de uma maneira que não gostaria, usando Jquery e checando campo a campo, não vai ficar uma solução elegante, mas vai resolver, embora eu preferisse que fosse usando Data Annotation.

Comment: Putz cara, tenho certeza que dá pra fazer algo do tipo... quando chegar em casa, juro que vou tentar criar um exemplo mínimo funcional. =D

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma classe que será o Atributo, com herança na classe abstrata [ValidationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) essa sendo validação do servidor, e implementa a interface [IClientValidatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) para criar validação do cliente.

*Classe:* **Attribute**

```
public class ValidationIfAposentado : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public String CompareProperty {get;set;}
    public string CompareValue { get; set; }
    public ValidationIfAposentado(String CompareProperty, String CompareValue)
    {
        this.CompareProperty = CompareProperty;
        this.CompareValue = CompareValue;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(CompareProperty);
        if (propertyInfo != null)
        {
            object valor = propertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
            if (!(valor != null && CompareValue.Equals(valor.ToString())))
            {  
               return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);                   
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
    IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> IClientValidatable.GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var erro = new ModelClientValidationRequiredRule(this.ErrorMessage);
        erro.ValidationType = "validationifaposentado";
        erro.ValidationParameters.Add("item", CompareProperty);
        erro.ValidationParameters.Add("value", CompareValue);            
        yield return erro;
    }
}
```

*Classe:* **Trabalhador**

```
public class Trabalhador
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    [MinLength(1), MaxLength(1)]
    public String Aposentado { get; set; }

    [ValidationIfAposentado("Aposentado", "S", ErrorMessage="Como é aposentado digite a data de aposentadoria")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? DataAposentadoria { get; set; }
}
```

Na classe `Trabalhador`, foi feita uma adição do `?` ou [`System.Nullable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) no `DataAposentadoria`, visto que o mesmo só vai ter valor se o `Aposentado` for igual "**S**" se não gravar a `DataAposentadoria` como ***NULL***.

*Com o Atributo **ValidationIfAposentado** ele fará a verificação e validação no servidor.*

Para validação via cliente ([Javascript](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)) deverá ser implementado esse javascript logo abaixo que é correspondente a validação do servidor.

*Javascript:* Código utilizando essas referências do [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [jQuery.Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) e [jQuery.Unobtrusive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation/3.1.2).

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script> 
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("validationifaposentado", ["item", "value"],
        function (options) {
            options.rules['validationifaposentado'] = {
                item: "#" + options.params.item,
                value: options.params.value, 
            }
            options.messages["validationifaposentado"] = options.message;                
        });
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("validationifaposentado", function (value, element, params) {            
        if ($(params.item).val() === undefined || $(params.item).val() == '') {
            return true;
        }       
        return $(params.item).val() == params.value && value != '' && value.length == 10;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Senhores, a solução do FCCDias funcionou, porem tive que fazer uma pequena alteração, eu não quis alterar o seu codigo, pois não consegui entender bem aquele bloco de JavaScript, mas  unica alteração que fiz foi na antepenultima linha:
Não Funcionou: return $(params.item).val() == params.value && value != '' && value.length == 10;
Funcionou: Return "";

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda;